# Mailcore2: How to add signature to message

Tags: ios, email-client, mailcore2

Is there any API available in MailCore2 library for adding signature in email message?

Comment: you might like to check source in this post https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/495

Answer (score 0):

Get your email body as is:

```
NSString *oldEmailBodyString = [emailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];
```

Then add you signature to it:

```
NSString *signature = @"<p>Sent from my iPhone</p>";
NSString *newEmailBodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@ %@</html>", oldEmailBodyString, signature];
```

Load your new email body from string:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath];
[emailWebView loadHTMLString:newEmailBodyString baseURL:baseURL];
```